# How to make backslash based URL with .htaccess?

Tags: url, .htaccess

My site is in php. I want to convert the following..

domain.com/download.php?type=wallpaper&id=123456&name=windows-7

to something like this..

domain.com/download/wallpaper/123456/windows-7.html

I want people to make the second link to work in my page. When one open the second link it will open the page like what I have in the first link. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ download.php?type=$1&id=$2&name=$3
```

Comment: Why is this not working?


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?type=$1&page=$2

I want to go to this.. domain.com/wallpaper/2

Comment: @GanChinHock.com: The pattern has a trailing slash but your URL path doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

Expecting, you are using Apache HTTP server:

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and optionally [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html